# Making it so lines created with distance and direction tool don't show angle label

Tags: arcgis-pro

As the following image illustrates, when I'm adding a line using the Distance and Direction tool in ArcGIS labels are automatically added. If the vertices are sufficiently close to one another these labels effectively hide the labels. Is there a way to disable the addition of or hide these labels?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tool creates a layer, you can see it in the Contents panel. So you can simply turn off the labelling.

[image: label]